# how to navigate submenu items using React Router Dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

i'm creating a react app that contains sidebar with sub items.

i want to open  and  components under manage/ url **( like manage/sub1, manage/sub2 ).**

i tried to create a nested route inside /manage but it's redirecting to again to /manage. is there any way to do this?

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<PublicRoute />}>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="manage" element={<Manage />} />
        <Route path="sub1" element={<Sub1 />} />
        <Route path="sub2" element={<Sub2 />} />
      </Route>

    </Routes>
  </div>
);
```

---

my sidebar navigation code

```
<NavItem link="/manage" icon={HappinessIcon} label="Manage" hasSubItem>
 <div>
    <NavSubItem link="/sub1" label="Sub Item 1" />
    <NavSubItem link="/sub2" label="Sub Item 2" />
 </div>
</NavItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading the v6 documentation i figured out nesting won't help me in this situation. i just need to add manage/ in front of all the sub items.

```
<Route path="manage/sub1" element={<Sub1 />} />
<Route path="manage/sub2" element={<Sub2 />} />
```

---

on my sidebar navigation code

```
<NavItem link="/manage" icon={HappinessIcon} label="Manage" hasSubItem>
 <div>
    <NavSubItem link="/manage/sub1" label="Sub Item 1" />
    <NavSubItem link="/manage/sub2" label="Sub Item 2" />
 </div>
</NavItem>
```

---

*that's all i had to do, if you know any clean solution than this let me know.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to nest routes you can use a combination of layout and index routes to accomplish it.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<PublicRoute />}>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  </Route>
  <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
    <Route path="/dashboard/*">
      <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/manage/*">                   // layout to allow nested route matching
      <Route index element={<Manage />} />     // "/mangage"
      <Route path="sub1" element={<Sub1 />} /> // "/mangage/sub1"
      <Route path="sub2" element={<Sub2 />} /> // "/mangage/sub2"
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

If the `Manage` component is rendering links they can be relative links

```
<NavSubItem link="sub1" label="Sub Item 1" />
<NavSubItem link="sub2" label="Sub Item 2" />
```

Otherwise if you are rendering all the links from a single component in/at/near the root then you'll likely need to use absolute links.

```
<NavSubItem link="/manage/sub1" label="Sub Item 1" />
<NavSubItem link="/manage/sub2" label="Sub Item 2" />
```

The difference between relative and absolute links is the leading slash `"/"` character.